# What are continous coefficients in an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have studied ODEs but today my teacher asked a question, that I was confused about:
*If an ODE is given as a linear initial value problem in normalized form, where
coefficients are continuous,then will the solution be
be unique?*
I don't understand by what my prof meant by continous coefficients in an ODE, and would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: the coefficient may be a function and in this case the function is given to be continuous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODE is *linear* with leading coefficient $1$ (which is the meaning of *normalized*), that is,
$$
y^{(n)}(x)+a_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}(x)+\ldots+a_0(x)y(x)=r(x).
$$
The assumption is that all coefficients $a_k$ and right side $r$ are continuous functions. Then the equation is globally Lipschitz in every strip over a bounded $x$-interval, with the claimed consequences on existence and uniqueness.